# retrieve gate errors from rigetti devices via braket

Tags: amazon-braket, rigetti

Is it possible to retrieve gate fidelities, T1 and T2 times, etc. from old jobs in a rigetti device via braket and the amazon api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access historic calibration data, including gate fidelities and T1 and T2 times, via Amazon Braket today.

If you send an email to braket-feedback@amazon.com with your use case, including the date range, the Braket team can follow up with you directly to see if there is any other way to assist, as well as to improve the product.